# Closure with inside handler wrong

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

The handlers are good, but I am not getting the right closure inside the handler. `this.$.success.open();` is not finding the element with `id=success`. How can I get the closure correct?

```
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'rsvp-wedding',
      properties: {
        httpError: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        }
      },
      _submit: function(event) {
        Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
      },
      errorResponse: function(e) {
        console.log(e.detail.request.status);
        console.log(e);
        this.$.error.open();
      }.bind(this),
      successResponse: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (e.detail.status === 200) {
          this.$.success.open();
        } else {
          this.errorResponse(e);
        }
      }.bind(this),
      attached: function() {
        var form = document.querySelector('form');
        form.addEventListener('iron-form-error', this.errorResponse);
        form.addEventListener('iron-form-response', this.successResponse);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: What is the outer `this` that you're binding with `.bind(this)` supposed to be? This code isn't in an object method.

Comment: This is polymer.... `this.$.elementId` would be the same as `document.querySelector('#elementId')`. `this` would refer to the functions and api's inside of the `Polymer` constructor.

Comment: I don't think you need that outer bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're seeing this error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined`

which does **not** mean that it cannot find the element with ID of "success" but rather that `this.$` is undefined, and you're trying to access a property named "success" from it.

In your code, you're actually binding to the outer scope's `this`, which is the Window object (as seen in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uz2u2cwr/)), so that binding should be removed.

To bind to the Polymer object, call `bind(this)` inside one of the Polymer object's methods. In your case, you'd do it when you add the event listener:

```
attached: function() {
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  form.addEventListener('iron-form-error', this.errorResponse.bind(this));
  form.addEventListener('iron-form-response', this.successResponse.bind(this));
}
```

Here's a demo with a similar event firing element:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  <x-bar></x-bar>
  
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        ready: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.fire('foo');
          }.bind(this), 1000);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="x-bar">
    <template>
      <span id="msg">{{foo}}</span>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-bar',
        properties : {
          foo: {
            type: String,
            value: "Hello world!"
          }
        },
        changeMessageColor: function() {
          this.$.msg.style.color = "red";
        },
        attached: function() {
          var foo = document.querySelector('x-foo');
          foo.addEventListener('foo', this.changeMessageColor.bind(this));
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kupuna/edit?html,output)</sup>

Another way to do this without `.bind(this)` is to use Polymer's [`listen()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#imperative-listeners):

```
attached: function() {
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  this.listen(form, 'iron-form-error', 'errorResponse');
  this.listen(form, 'iron-form-response', 'successResponse');
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  <x-bar></x-bar>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        ready: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.fire('foo');
          }.bind(this), 1000);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="x-bar">
    <template>
      <span id="msg">{{foo}}</span>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-bar',
        properties: {
          foo: {
            type: String,
            value: "Hello world!"
          }
        },
        changeMessageColor: function() {
          this.$.msg.style.color = "red";
        },
        attached: function() {
          var foo = document.querySelector('x-foo');
          this.listen(foo, 'foo', 'changeMessageColor');
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/levaxoc/edit?html,output)</sup>